# How to switch off interpreter log in MIT-Scheme when loading files

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

This is a very specific question but I have been trying to get this to work for two days without success.

I am using MIT-Scheme (Release 7.7.90 on Ubuntu 10.04) to run some Scheme scripts.
My command line looks as follow

```
mit-scheme --band "myimage.com" --interactive --batch-mode < myscript.scm
```

My problem is that if the main script loads other Scheme files, the interpreter logs this by printing somethig like:

```
;Loading "....scm"... done
;Loading "....scm"... 
;  Loading "....scm"... done
;  Loading "....scm"... 
;    Loading "....scm"... done
;  ... done
;... done
;Loading "....scm"... done
```

This is very annoying because my script also logs some progress information which gets mixed up with the above output. So, I would like to suppress the output from the load procedure completely.

I have been looking through the [online documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/index.html) but I haven't found anything specific. The only solution I have found consists in loading the script with all its dependencies into the interpreter and saving an image with disk-save. If I then load that image with the --band option all the unwanted output is gone.

But of course I do not want to load the source and save an image each time I modify a source file. Is there a simpler solution, e.g. a command-line option, an environment variable, or some option that can be set from within the Scheme code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little late, but for anyone stumbling on this later:

You can use `load/suppress-loading-message?`

e.g. doing a `(set! load/suppress-loading-message? #t)` will turn off the loading message.

In your case, you should try `--eval "(set! load/suppress-loading-message? #t)"`

Comment: You rock! (+1) It works perfectly! Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: I added the suggested line at the beginning of my main script and it did the job.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere but you can see it defined in src/runtime/load.scm of the MIT-Scheme source code.

Comment: Anyway, it works. Now I can use MIT-Scheme also for scripting. Very nice.